# zeppelin-0.73 spark2.1 hdp2.3.4 Yarn killed

Tags: apache-zeppelin

when I use spark on yarn under Keberos ，it work good，but when I use zeppelin ,I meet a question, I use hdp2.3.4 and spark2.1 and zeppelin0.73 
who can tell the reason

> arn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master

this zeppelin error info as follow:

```
aused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    ... 20 more
ERROR [2018-06-27 09:47:21,610] ({pool-2-thread-4} Job.java[run]:181) - Job 
   failed
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at 
    org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
```

Comment: check the yarn app log for more detail errors

Comment: think you,I look yarn log  the error is : Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher , but the same condition ,I only use spark_submit,it work well

Comment: Do you specify SPARK_HOME in zeppelin, if not it would run in embedded mode which doesn't support yarn mode

Comment: Yesnow I get yarn log, the error is :

Comment: thank you for tips,yes I also set SPARK_HOME in zeppelin.  now I get yarn log, the error is : Error: Could not find or load main class  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher ,but I also set  spark.yarn.jars hdfs://tdcluster/user/hdpclient/sparkjars/* in spark-defaults.conf  file, and it work well

Comment: You don't need to specify spark.yarn.jars, if everything is configured correctly, spark will look for the right jar for you. Make sure your spark distribution support yarn, try to use run spark-shell in yarn mode first to verify it